# Magento search form not working

Tags: magento

Using the seach form in the shop outputs the "Whoops, our bad..." page.

I've seen similar questions but rebuilding the index is not solving the problem.

The search form sends to http://...//catalogsearch/result/?q=... and fails. But if I use the advanced search url http://...//catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=...  it works fine.

Any idea of what can be causing this behaviuor. The shop has recently been upgraded from magento 1.5.X to 1.6.0 and then to 1.6.1

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions - More than likely your upgrade went sour in some sense, the controller isn't being found.

Comment: Yes thta must be. Any ideas of what could have gone wrong or how to trak it to get the cause?

Comment: Have you tried this with the default package & theme? For me it was a theme issue, somewhere between 1.3 and 1.6 search started requiring a block type="catalogsearch/layer" to be instantiated in the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar happened to me and the problem was that the upgrade wasn't completed.

Make sure you've no dependencies problems or conflicts when upgrading.

If you get errors with dependencies, try uninstalling non core modules and then try to install magento latest again. Make sure the errors disappear.

Once the upgrade is correct you can re-install uninstalled modules, if they work in the latest magento version.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. Reindex from terminal. I had the same problem. Reindexing from the backoffice wouldn't work, but after reindexing from terminal, everything went back to normal.

```
php /path/to/magento/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```